# Next image name from SQL

Tags: jquery, sql-server, image, gallery

I am trying to create a gallery for my Web, I need to make two buttons, next and prev. I generate image name from SQL table and I am trying to make a function, when you click "next arrow" to take next image name from the table and when you click "prev arrow" you take previous name from it. Is there any simple call in SQL to get value of next column image name ?

I tried to look it up before I posted it here but couldn't find anything specific

Comment: please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). your question is missing lots of information that are critical to help you. also you can't interact with sql using jquery: you must have 'something' in between (php, asp.net, ...)

Comment: No there is no simple built in "call" for this.   You're going to have to do some programming.

Comment: okay did that thing with javascript/php, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't do like this, just call all rows and from array with coding language you can choose next value.